# how to add two python dictionaries with the same numeric order?

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries that looks something like this example:

```py
A = {0: {"a":1} 1: {"b":2} 2: {"c":3}}
B = {0: {"z":99} 1: {"y":98} 2: {"x":97}}
```

If I use `**` or `|` the second one overwrites the first one.
How can I add those two, even tho they have the same numeric order.
Can I change the numbers of the second dict or is there another way to add them?

In the end it should look something like this:

```
C = {0: {"a":1} 1: {"b":2} 2: {"c":3} 3: {"z":99} 4: {"y":98} 5: {"x":97}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add"? Can you provide an example of what the output should look like, as well as code showing your attempts?

Answer (score 2):

If the keys of the second dict (or all subsequent dicts if more than one) don't matter and only have to be ordered, you can create a dict from the enumeration of the values of all dicts, using `dict`, `itertools.chain`, and `enumerate`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> A = {0: {"a":1}, 1: {"b":2}, 2: {"c":3}}
>>> B = {0: {"z":99}, 1: {"y":98}, 2: {"x":97}}
>>> C = dict(enumerate(itertools.chain(A.values(), B.values())))
>>> C
{0: {'a': 1}, 1: {'b': 2}, 2: {'c': 3}, 3: {'z': 99}, 4: {'y': 98}, 5: {'x': 97}}
```

If there are more than two dictionaries (i.e., A, B, C, D, ...etc), then using this is probably better:

```
G = dict(enumerate(itertools.chain(*map(dict.values, (A, B, C, D, E, F)))))
```